# Nested Arrays Issue using Symfony 5/Twig "Array to string conversion"

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I try to display a simple `a` link using :

Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler

and

Symfony\Component\Panther\Client

I need to extract `h2` > `a` and display them to twig

in My class controller :

```
$linkMetaInfo = [];
$crawler->filter('h2 a')->each(function (Crawler $node) use (&$linkMetaInfo) {

        $linkMetaInfo['link'][] = $node->attr('href');
        $linkMetaInfo['text'][] = $node->text();

    });
 return $linkMetaInfo;
```

route controller :

```
        return $this->render('home/display-meta.html.twig', [

        'linkMetaInfos' => $linkMetaInfos

        ]);
```

Dump :

```
array:2 [▼
  "linkMetaInfos" => array:2 [▼
    "link" => array:27 [▼
      0 => "https://bootstrapmade.com/flexstart-bootstrap-startup-template/"
      1 => "https://bootstrapmade.com/bootslander-free-bootstrap-landing-page-template/"
      2 => "https://bootstrapmade.com/arsha-free-bootstrap-html-template-corporate/"
      3 => "https://bootstrapmade.com/free-bootstrap-template-corporate-moderna/"
      4 => "https://bootstrapmade.com/free-html-bootstrap-template-my-resume/"
      5 => "https://bootstrapmade.com/iportfolio-bootstrap-portfolio-websites-template/"
      ]
    "text" => array:27 [▼
      0 => "FlexStart"
      1 => "Bootslander"
      2 => "Arsha"
      3 => "Moderna"
      4 => "MyResume"
      5 => "iPortfolio]
  ]
  "app" => Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable {#178 ▶}
]
```

in my twig view :

```
{% for linkMetaInfo  in linkMetaInfos %}
    
    <a href="{{ linkMetaInfos.link }}">{{ linkMetaInfos.text }}</a>

    {% endfor %}
```

If i do :

```
{{ dump(linkMetaInfos.link) }}
```

or

```
{{ dump(linkMetaInfos.link) }}
```

everything is fine

But when i try :

```
<a href="{{ linkMetaInfos.link }}">{{ linkMetaInfos.text }}</a>
```

I got this message :

**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion").**

if i try  :

```
{{ dump(linkMetaInfo.text) }}
```

or

```
{{ dump(linkMetaInfo.link) }}
```

I got this message :

**Key "link" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26" does not exist.**

Any idea ?
for advance thank's

Comment: if your solution differs from the proposed by others please, add it in the answer section and not inside the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say it's a nested array, so you've to loop inside the nested array, no ?

In this next exemple, you're looping inside the links, and make a coordination with the text, but be carreful of having the same length...

```
{% for linkMetaInfo  in linkMetaInfos.link %}
     <a href="{{ linkMetaInfo }}">{{ linkMetaInfos.text[loop.index0] }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Merci Patrick !!
it works perfectly 
Nested array ? good question

my goal was to include this 2 arrays into an array named h2Content :

[linkMetaInfos
      -> [h2Content
         ->[link]
         ->[text]
       ]
]